# Getting dates of password changed in journalctl

Tags: password, journalctl

I can get the last password changed using `passwd -Sa`, but how to get 2nd last password change date? and if possible its IP Address?

Answer (score 0):

> how to get 2nd last password change date?

Like this?

```
sudo passwd -Sa | tail -2 | head -1 | awk '{ print $3 }'
05/15/2016
```

`tail -2` prints the two last lines in the output from `passwd -Sa`, `head -1` prints the first of those two lines (i.e. the second to last line), `awk '{ print $3 }'` prints the 3rd field from that output:

```
   -S, --status
   [snip]
   The third field gives the date of the last password change.
```

Don't know about getting the IP address though.

Comment: ah sorry, no I mean 2nd last password changed from a user.